# How to keep an connection to sqlite open through out the App

Tags: ios, sqlite

I am developing an app driven from sqlite and the app load data from the database on every user interaction. What I have decided is to keep the SQLlite connection active through the app.

Thank you

Comment: How long is it going to be between user interactions?  And why have you "decided" to keep the connection active?

Comment: I have seen it recommended online. Use interaction will be every second sometimes as they are browsing through the folders which are stored in the sqlite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I can create a sqlite3 return type method in the application delegate and save the sqlite connection in the sqlite3 object. When ever I need to open sqlite connection I just call that method